# induction on matrices with powers + addition and limit

Tags: matrices, induction

$A= \begin{bmatrix}
1-q && p \\
q && 1-q
\end{bmatrix},  0<p<1, 0<q<1,$

Using mathematical induction show that

$A^n$ = $\frac{1}{p+q}\begin{bmatrix}
q && p \\
q && p
\end{bmatrix}$ + $\frac{(1-p-q)^n}{p+q}\begin{bmatrix}
p && -p \\
-q && q
\end{bmatrix}$

Assuming $|1-p-q|<1$ find $\lim_{n\to \infty} P^n$.

I know $A^{n+1} = A^n *A$, so 
assumption is 
$A^k = \frac{1}{p+q}\begin{bmatrix}
q && p \\
q && p
\end{bmatrix}$ + $\frac{(1-p-q)^k}{p+q}\begin{bmatrix}
p && -p \\
-q && q
\end{bmatrix}$

And we need to show that

$A^{k+1} =\frac{1}{p+q}\begin{bmatrix}
q && p \\
q && p
\end{bmatrix}$ + $\frac{(1-p-q)^{k+1}}{p+q}\begin{bmatrix}
p && -p \\
-q && q
\end{bmatrix}$

So $A^{k+1} = A^k * A = \frac{1}{p+q}\begin{bmatrix}
q && p \\
q && p
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
1-q && p \\
q && 1-q
\end{bmatrix}$ +$\frac{(1-p-q)^{k+1}}{p+q}\begin{bmatrix}
p && -p \\
-q && q
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
1-q && p \\
q && 1-q
\end{bmatrix}$

and I'm stuck from here on! I can't seem to get past this point. When I do multiplication on them it looks nothing like it's supposed to.

Answer (score 1):

If this is true for all $n=1,2,3\ldots$ then $A=A^1$ must be eqial to

$$A= \begin{bmatrix}
1-q && p \\
q && 1-q
\end{bmatrix}=\frac{1}{p+q}\begin{bmatrix}
q && p \\
q && p
\end{bmatrix} + \frac{(1-p-q)^1}{p+q}\begin{bmatrix}
p && -p \\
-q && q
\end{bmatrix}$$

For the ellement in the upper left corner we have 
$$1-q=\frac{q}{p+q}+p\left(\frac{1}{p+q}-1\right)=\frac{q}{p+q}+\frac{p}{p+q}-p=1-p$$

which is evidently correct only if $p=q$. May me there is a misprint in the conditions of the question?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a typo. The correct statement is perhaps
$$
A=\pmatrix{1-q&p\\ q&1-\color{red}{p}}
\ \Rightarrow\ A^n=
\frac1{p+q}\pmatrix{p&p\\ q&q} + \frac{(1-p-q)^n}{p+q}\pmatrix{q&-p\\ -q&p}
$$
or its transposed version, so that you are asked to determine the power of a [stochastic matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_matrix).

Comment: Yes I looked into it and it is indeed a typo, though switching the (1,1) and (2,2) elements from what you've suggested. Made my life much easier.